# DO Loop Until Reverse. Tricky

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have created a table displaying rows and columns of Numbers and underscores using the DO WHILE function. I was supposed to use the DO Loop Until function.  I am having trouble doing it in the DO Loop Until function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```vb
Dim outSideCounter As Integer
Dim inSideCounter As Integer

outSideCounter = 0
inSideCounter = 0

Do While outSideCounter <= 4
    '36 underscores
    lblDisplayTable.Text = lblDisplayTable.Text & "________________" & vbCr & vbCr
    outSideCounter = outSideCounter + 1

    Do While inSideCounter <= 4
        inSideCounter = inSideCounter + 1
        lblDisplayTable.Text = lblDisplayTable.Text & "col #" & inSideCounter & "     "
    Loop
    inSideCounter = 0
    lblDisplayTable.Text = lblDisplayTable.Text & vbCr
```

Comment: What is the problem with your Do...Until ? You just posted the Do While...

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `do while` and `do loop until` is that the former always performs the check *before* doing work, and the latter does one unit of work and *then* does the check. So, you would use the until statement when you know there is already some work to do and want to save the check for later.

Also note that the meaning of the condition changes. In the case of using `while`, you're *continuing* to do work as long as the condition is true. In the case of `until`, you'll *stop* doing work when the condition is true. So, the condition will be different between the two variations to get the same result. Thanks to commenter @Strilanc for pointing that out.

Comment: Also, the check is reversed. `until` keeps going while the conditions if false, whereas `while` keeps going while it's true.